# Is this syntax not right for executing an APOC query?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
call apoc.index.nodes('Product', 'name:iPhone*') yield node return node
```

In my graph I have 'iPhone X' and 'iPhone Plus', but this query doesn't return anything. I also have an index on 'name' property of Product.

```
Indexes
   ON :Product(name) ONLINE
```

Answer (score 3):

`apoc.index.nodes` is one of the [APOC procedures for "manual indexes"](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_and_lookup_indexes), which are also confusingly referred to in various docs as "legacy indexes" and "explicit indexes". Such indexes use the [Apache Lucene library](https://lucene.apache.org/) and are NOT the same as the standard neo4j indexes that most people use, and the way you create/update/use such indexes is also not standard.

For example, you cannot create a "manual index" via a Cypher `CREATE INDEX` clause. And neo4j Browser's `:schema` command will not show any manual indexes.

If you will only be searching `:Product(name)` via manual indexes, then you should drop your standard index for `:Product(name)`, since it will not be needed but will add overhead (time and space) to your DB.

One way to create/update/use manual indexes is through the special APOC procedures. The APOC documentation for manual indexes (linked above) provides a good amount of information about how to add nodes and relationships to such indexes, and how to search using them.

As an example, before you can use the query in your question, you first have to add all the `:Product(name)` values to the `Product` manual index. If you want to add them all at once, you can use the following query (and since it has to return something, it just returns a count of the number of `Product`s):

```
MATCH (p:Product)
CALL apoc.index.addNode(p, ['name'])
RETURN count(*)
```

[UPDATED]

Manual indexing is typically only used for partial and fuzzy text search use cases. When you just need exact value matching, standard indexes are recommended, especially since they require *much less effort* on your part. The reason manual indexes are called "manual" is because the responsibility for maintaining them falls entirely on your shoulders. That is, your node/relationship/property addition/removal/update queries would normally have to add/remove/update any relevant manual index entries as well. Note that when you *update* a property that is manually indexed, you have to remove the old index entry and then add the new entry.

Comment: Now I know how to use it. What's the best time to use APOC manual index? I usually want to create all indexes ready when the database is built. It seems manual indexes are used for some certain queries at certain situations, created and queried at runtime? Is that true? Specifically, I want to index all properties on my ProductAttribute nodes and to be able to fuzzy full text match on these properties. What's the best way to build the index using APOC?

Comment: I added a paragraph to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Does APOC manual index exist after I restart my neo4j? Or they only exist at one query session?

Comment: Manual indexes persist across queries, and even across server sessions.

Comment: I have many Attribute nodes with different properties. I want to index all Attribute nodes's properties systematically and to be able to perform fuzzy search. What's the best way to build index for those properties? Ideally, it should be a sub-process of building the graph itself.